# I am trying to divide a array into three parts and put it into list of lists using python but i keep getting error when running the code

Tags: python, arrays, list

Here's my code sample:

```py
from typing import List
class Solution4:
    def sort(self, arr: List[int]) -> int:
        if (len(arr) % 3 == 0):
            triplet_group = int (len(arr)/3)
            nonlocal triplet
            triplet : [[]] * triplet_group
            for i in range (triplet_group):
                j = i+1
                for x in range (len(arr)):
                    nonlocal triplet
                    triplet[i].append(arr[(i*triplet_group)+j])
            print(triplet)
```

I keep getting two errors :

1. Unbound local error for variable `triplet`
2. annotated 'triplet' variable cannot be used as global

Comment: Is `triplet` defined outside the `sort` function?

Comment: Also, what are you trying to do in line `triplet : [[]] * triplet_group`?

Comment: And you are not using variable `x` anywhere

Comment: 1.) Triplet is not defined outside function.  2.) By doing this -  triplet : [[]] * triplet_group, I am trying to make the 3(len(arr)/3) lists inside of outer List

Comment: I actually figured it out guys. Thank you for the help though !!